# how can I transform a column into array

Tags: google-apps-script

in a google apps script, I try to tranform data spread in a column into an array.
I would like to know if there is any better way to code this, maybe without using a loop ?

```
function myFunction3() {
  var dataInCol = [['A'], ['B'], ['C'], ['D'], ['E'], ['F'], ['G']] ;

  var dataInRow = [] ;
  var i = 0 ;
  while ( i < dataInCol.length ) {
    dataInRow.push( dataInCol[i][0] ) ;
    i++ ;
  }

  // logger returns : ' [A, B, C, D, E, F, G] '
  Logger.log( dataInRow ) ;
}
```

Many thanks !

Comment: What's the problem? What's the goal? What did you try, that failed to work?

Comment: The aim is to search for a value with indexOf().

I got my search function to work in a column even in a line, by combining them :  `.flat().flat()`
It means that i search for a value in a row or a column with 
`Logger.log( range.indexOf(valueToSearch).flat().flat() )` in which `range` is like `[['A'], ['B'], ['C']]` or like `['A', 'B', 'C']`

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.prototype.flat

```js
var arr = [['A'], ['B'], ['C'], ['D'], ['E'], ['F'], ['G']];
console.log(arr.flat())
```